# Drawing Images to fit circle

Tags: c#

I'm making an inventory screen for a game I'm working on, and I'd like to be able to draw a series of panels representing each item in the inventory. I want to be able to fit those panels on a circular path.
 Here's a mock up I made of what I mean

http://fc02.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2010/280/7/2/khmp_magic_menu_concept_by_magna_alphamon-d30a7em.png

basically I'd like to be able to, give a radius, a center point, and the y co-ordinate to start drawing at, draw this series of panels so they align with the path of the circle like in the image.

Computing the y dimension is easy, its just the startposition y + panel height * panel index, but I'm unsure how to compute the x for a variable radius/center point circle.

Any help would be appreciated.

This is in C#, but something similar in C/C++ will be fine as long as I can convert it

Thanks in advance

EDIT: To calirify, y's position is relative to the top or bottom of the screen and is independent of the circle. If a given y does not map to a point on the circle, then I'll discard that point and not draw the panel.

While ideally I'd like to be able to use any elliptical shape (given two radii), a circle would be good too

Comment: Now you want an ellipse, which is a completely different question.  It is much trickier on an ellipse, so you should choose one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

Let cx, cy be the coordinates of the center point.  Let r be the radius of the circle.  Let y be the drawing y-coordinate and x, the x-coordinate.  You observe that y = cy + panel height * panel index.  By the magic of right triangles, this means that x^2 + y^2 = r^2.  Solving for x, we get `x = cx + sqrt(r^2 - (y-cy)^2)`.

EDIT:  Converting to code:

```
#include <math>
float ordinate(float cx, float cy, float r, float y) {
    // assumes cx and cy are in the same coordinate system as x and y
    // assumes the coordinate origin is in the lower left corner.
    return cx + sqrtf(powf(r,2) - powf(y-cy,2));
}
```

Comment: @Ed:  I didn't think it was.  You're just pushing for an equispaced in angle solution when the question was (more or less) for equispaced vertically.  I.e. you're not converting his inputs to output.  You're converting an angle he doesn't know into an output that he already has half of.

Comment: I guess my thought is that it is easy to get the angle between each because you know the arc length of the circle, so it is simple division and conversion to radians.

Comment: But really, whatever works and is easiest.  It is true that I used my code to populate objects around the entire circumference of a circle, not just a section of it.

Comment: He didn't want them equispaced in angle nor equispaced in arc.  He wanted them equispaced vertically.  So the delta-angle is small near horizontal and large near vertical.  To turn picky up to 11, he wanted to supply a height and get an x-value on the circle.  It just turns out that his heights are nearly evenly spaced.

Answer (score 0):

I'm dumb. After seeing Eric's answer, I remembered I can just rearrange and solve the equations of a circle or elipse as necessary.

Thanks

Answer (score -3):

You can use a rotational matrix for this.  Here is a simple algorithm that finds the next point {x, y} such that it is rotated theta radians around a circle.  You can start with the first item at x=radius and y=radius (wherever really, just a point that you know will contain an item), and then just continue to increment theta as you loop through your items.

```
Point Rotate(int x, int y, float theta)
  int x_p = (x * Math.Cos(theta)) - (y * Math.Sin(theta));
  int y_p = (y * Math.Cos(theta)) + (x * Math.Sin(theta));
  return new Point(x_p, y_p);
end
```

On a side note;  I always preferred "Bolt1, Bolt2, Bolt3" to "Thunder, Thundara, Thundaga" =P

Comment: It's not straightforward to make this emit evenly spaced y_p, one for each panel.  (The change in angle is not constant.)

Comment: Then it is an ellipse and not a circle, so the question is wrong.  If it is a circle and theta isn't constant it doesn't make a difference.  The function returns a point {x,y} that is theta radians around a circle.  the delta in theta is irrelevant.

Comment: Finding equidistant points around an ellipse is far less trivial than doing the same thing around a circle.

Comment: the problem is I don't know what theta is, and the length of the arc that needs to be free from panels varies depending where the panels need to be drawn on the circle so I cant depend on that to find theta

Comment: I don't see why you can't find a theta to rotate by from your comment.  Start at one point, figure out the arc length of the circle you need to fill, divide by the number of items and convert that to an angle in radians.

Comment: @Ed:  Wrong.  Have you looked at his linked image?  The panel origins lie on a circle.  The center of the circle is somewhere to the left of the screen, the diameter is about the height of the screen, and the set of y_p he needs are evenly spaced.

Comment: @Eric:  I have used this code in a video game I made for this exact purpose. It works, you are mistaken.